# Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain], exit code [-1]

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, oozie

I am trying to execute **Spark job** through **Oozie** on yarn cluster. Here is my workflow.xml

```
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5" name="SampleWF1">
<start to="myfirstsparkjob"/>
<action name="myfirstsparkjob">
    <spark xmlns="uri:oozie:spark-action:0.1">
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <configuration>
            <property>
                <name>mapreduce.job.queuename</name>
                <value>${queueName}</value>
            </property>
        </configuration>
        <master>yarn-cluster</master>
        <mode>cluster</mode>
        <name>Spark Example</name>
        <class>CLASS_PATH</class>
        <jar>HDFS_PATH_TO_JAR</jar>
        <spark-opts>--conf spark.hadoop.yarn.resourcemanager.address=your-rm:8050</spark-opts>
    </spark>
    <ok to="end"/>
    <error to="fail"/>
</action>

<kill name="fail">
    <message>workflow failed</message>
</kill>
<end name="end"/> 
</workflow-app>
```

Jar which I have mentioned contains all the dependencies it require. I am using services as below
spark version 1.6.0.2.4
oozie version 4.2.0.2.4
HDP version 2.4.0.0-169

I am submitting oozie job through **yarn** user.
Below is my config.

```
nameNode=hdfs://host:8020
jobTracker=host:8050

oozie.use.system.libpath=true
userLoc=/user/oozie
oozie.libpath=${nameNode}${userLoc}/share/lib

currTimeScript=sample.sh
currTimeScriptPath=/user/oozie/workflows/test_flow
queueName=Aggregation
user.name=yarn
classPath=valid_class_path

oozieProjectRoot=${nameNode}${userLoc}/workflows
workFlowName=test_flow
workFlowHome=${oozieProjectRoot}/${workFlowName}
oozie.wf.application.path=${workFlowHome}/workflow.xml
```

Comment: check yarn application for full logs

Comment: @NirmalRam My fault in Hortonworks 2.4.x, Oozie does not supports Spark action.

Comment: HDP 2.4.x supports Spark action, that is why only your action got launched and failed. As already mentioned, you need to check the yarn/application-master logs for more information about the failure. Thanks.

Comment: @YoungHobbit thanks for point out that. But here http://hortonworks.com/apache/oozie/#section_4 they have told that support to Spark Action is in there future scope.

Comment: I believe you can ignore that, HDP Oozie supports Spark action, Please look into the launcher job logs. Thanks.